# Horizontal tabs in boostrtap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've using some code for custom vertical tabs in bootstrap and I trying to make them horizontal and text below every tab but I can't understand exactly how.

```
<section id="about">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="feature_header text-center">
                <h3 class="feature_title"><b>Tabs</b></h3>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="feature-tab">
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-tab-list text-center" role="tablist">
                      <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >
                          <div class="single-tab">
                                <div class="f-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <h4>Tab 1</h4>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" >
                        <a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <div class="single-tab">
                                <div class="f-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h4>Tab 2</h4>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" >
                        <a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <div class="single-tab">
                                <div class="f-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h4>Tab 3</h4>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                </ul>
            </div>  <!-- col-md-12 end -->
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="tab-content main-tab-content">
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active " id="home">

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9">
                                <div class="c-tab">
                                     <h4>Tab 1</h4>
                                     <p>Lorem ipsum.... </p>
                                     <a href="#"> More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active " id="home">

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9">
                                <div class="c-tab">
                                     <h4>Tab 2</h4>
                                     <p>Lorem ipsum.... </p>
                                     <a href="#"> More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active " id="home">

                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9">
                                <div class="c-tab">
                                     <h4>Tab 3</h4>
                                     <p>Lorem ipsum.... </p>
                                     <a href="#"> More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

I wont post CSS because will be very long instead I'll post the JsFiddle.

For more clear I have made this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j1srpjL/1/). Can some one tell how will this go horizontal. I mean `Tab 1`, `Tab 2` and `Tab 3`..

Comment: In `.main-tab-list li` change the css from `float:none;` to `float:left;`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @SujataChanda, thank's for answer but is still on the left and vertical insted of horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `.col-md` class from `.nav-tabs` parent and replace it by `.row` class, and your `` should be:

```
.main-tab-list li{
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     float: left; /* or none */

     padding: 10px 0px 10px;
     border: 1px solid#eee;
     width: 150px;
     /*background: #FBFBFB;*/
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yt21wup5/

Answer (score 3):

You can try as below, i just edited your below class and it works!
you should always give style `float: left;` and `display: inherit;` together to do the magic :)

```
.main-tab-list li{
padding: 10px 0px 10px;
border: 1px solid#eee;
width: 150px;
/* background: #FBFBFB; */
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inherit;
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It is still vertical on the left.. Currently is Vertical on the left and the text next to it on the right. I don't know why I can't reproduce it into jsfiddle. But the main point are tabs which I want above the text i.e. horizontal.